# How to retrieve real-time date from Firestore without StreamBuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter

To deal real-time changes on the Firestore, we should used StreamBuilder according to following page.
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes
But, I would like to deal without StreamBuilder (in other words “without Widget”).

Following code is I tried.

In most case, there is no problem. But, first data from stream/snapthot is rarely not existing (docSnapshot.exists == false ) , even if userProfile exists in the Firestore.

I think reason is beacause docSnapshot is still not connected to Firestore. I know that we can use connectionState property to check connection state, but to use connectionState, we should use StreamBuilder(AsyncSnapshot)...

```dart
class Wrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WrapperState createState() => _WrapperState();
}

class _WrapperState extends State<Wrapper> {
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<UserProfile>.value(
            value: DatabaseService(user: _user).userProfile),
      ],
      child: _buildMyApp(),
    );
    }

    Widget _buildMyApp() {
    return Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          /// UserProfile
        final _userProfile = Provider.of<UserProfile>(context);
        if (_userProfile == null) return CreateUserProfile();
                return MaterialApp(title:'MyApp', home:MyApp());
            }
        );
    }
}

class DatabaseService {
  final User user;
  DocumentReference userRef;

  DatabaseService({this.user}) {
        /// get UserProfile data
    userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid);
  }

    Stream<UserProfile> get userProfile {
    try {
            /// map snapshot to UserProfile ojb AND 
      return userRef
          .snapshots()
          .map((docSnapshot) => _userProfileFromFirestore(docSnapshot));
    } catch (e) {
      print('[get userProfile]ERROR: ${e.toString()}');
      return null;
    }
  }

    //create UserProfile obj 
  UserProfile _userProfileFromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot docSnapshot) {
    if (docSnapshot.exists) {
      return UserProfile(
        name: docSnapshot.data()['name'],
        birthday: docSnapshot.data()['birthday']
      );
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
｝
```

Comment: "But, I would like to deal without `StreamBuilder`" - so use `Stream.listen()` method

Comment: @pskink thank you for your answer !. but other answer is better for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore document has a `metadata` property which contains a boolean `isFromCache` value. You can use this to filter your stream like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .doc('aaa')
    .snapshots()
    .where((doc) => !doc.metadata.isFromCache);
```

In your case, it would be like

```
Stream<UserProfile> get userProfile {
    try {
            /// map snapshot to UserProfile ojb AND 
      return userRef
          .snapshots()
          .where((docSnapshot) => !docSnapshot.metadata.isFromCache)
          .map((docSnapshot) => _userProfileFromFirestore(docSnapshot));
    } catch (e) {
      print('[get userProfile]ERROR: ${e.toString()}');
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer and sample code!

Answer (score 0):

Just use a while loop to retrieve data every sec

while(true){

retreiveData()

}

Comment: thank you for your answer !. but other answer is better for me.