# how to check connection state of firestore snapshots without streambuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, get

I have an app that uses firebase authentication and firestore. I have a root widget that decide which part of the app should be displayed based on the local user value (whether logged in or not) and some other things. I am using an observable variable that takes the value from firestore as stream.

Below is one part of my FirebaseAuthService class:

```
Rxn<LocalUser> firestoreUserObs = Rxn<LocalUser>();

LocalUser get localUser => firestoreUserObs?.value;

firestoreUserObs.bindStream(streamFirestoreUser());


Stream<LocalUser> streamFirestoreUser() {
   
    final myUser = _db
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(firebaseUserObs.value?.uid)
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.exists) {
        print('=========EXISTS==========');
        return LocalUser.fromJson(firebaseUserObs.value?.uid, snapshot.data());
      } else {
        print('=========DOES NOT EXIST==========');
      }
    });
    return myUser;
  }
```

Below is part of the Root widget

```
GetX<FirebaseAuthService>(
        builder: (_) {
          if (auth.localUser != null) {
            bool isAnon = auth.localUser?.isAnonymous ?? false;
            if (!isAnon) {
              if (collectInfo.displayCollectInfoScreen) {
                return CollectInfoScreen();
              } else {
                return HomeWrapper();
              }
            } else {
              if (isDisplayedAnon) {
                return HomeWrapper();
              } else {
                return AnonUserIntroScreen();
              }
            }
          } else {
            return AuthWrapper();
          }
        },
      ),
```

I would like to add an additional if statement that checks the connection state of streamFirestoreUser() but without using streambuilder as it causes some issues in some parts of my app (namely when navigating with push).

is there any way to check the connection of the stream?

Comment: Have you checked if this [Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65575587/how-to-retrieve-real-time-date-from-firestore-without-streambuilder) would work out for your project?

Comment: @RobertG that is exactly what I am doing. The problem is that I would like to access snapshot.connectionState that can be accessed using streambuilder, but without using.

Comment: Hi @AliAlqallaf. Did you find a solution? I have the same question...

Comment: Unfortunately no, I had to use stream builder